# How to Insert values into another colomn of SQL Table where first coloumn is taking values using execute xp_cmdshell?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, scripting

I am inserting .bak files name into sql table(TMP) from a folder contaning .bak files using below code.

**

```
CREATE  table TMP(FILENAME VARCHAR(100))
declare @filename varchar(100)
declare @filepath varchar(100)='S:\Common\Backups\'
insert into TMP execute xp_cmdshell 'dir S:\Common\Backups /b'
```

**

Now i also have to insert Date/time of the files in that folder.
How to insert Date/Time or say any other variable into same Table(in this case TMP)

When i try below code it gives error message

```
insert into TMP (FILENAME,DATE_Modified) values(execute xp_cmdshell 'dir S:\Common\Backups /b',01/01/2000 )
```

Error Message: 
***Coloumn name or Number of supplied Values does not match table defination***

How can i insert another variable into another colomn of the same table??

Comment: If it's hard coded anyway, you can use your first import and simply update the table after it: `update tmp set date_modified = '2000-01-01'`

Comment: @ZoharPeled I jus added the Date for the refrence, its not hard coded, it has to be inserted into the table, but during creating the table when i am declaring the  table with another parameter its giving error for exp: `CREATE  table TMP(FILENAME VARCHAR(100), Date_Modified date)` 
It gives below error : **Coloumn name or Number of supplied Values does not match table defination**

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you try set to variable before insert and return the `filepath` from your stored procedure

```
DECLARE @return varchar(100)
EXEC @return = xp_cmdshell 'dir S:\Common\Backups /b'
insert into TMP (FILENAME,DATE_Modified) values(@return,GETDATE()) --change to your Date or keep it for current date
```

Comment: I tried that as well but it errors out as "Must declare scalar variable @return  "

Comment: fixed try again

Comment: code works but not purpose of EXEC @return = xp_cmdshell 'dir S:\Common\Backups /b' was to save all files from a folder to table is lost, now its not saving files into the table

Comment: EXEC @return = xp_cmdshell 'dir S:\Common\Backups /b' are same as you call execute xp_cmdshell 'dir S:\Common\Backups /b' just get a return value from store procedure it shouldn't affect any procedure process

Comment: I guess when before inserting into table this command where declared   EXEC @return = xp_cmdshell 'dir S:\Common\Backups /b'  is getting executed and than later it is not able to insert into table